# AJAX call fails for signed Release APK and works fine for Signed Debug build

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, apk, cordova-plugins

I have one hybrid application which works fine for **signed debug build** and once we create the **signed release APK**, ajax call shows time out error. Could any one please help me.

onclick of login I am calling one ajax which calls the web service with https.it shows timeout in the **signed release APK** ans works fine in the **signed debug build**.

I checked the tab content policy, cordova whitelist plugin, config everything is fine. Is there any way to track release APK errors? I am stuck with this issue from past 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you post the error log.

Comment: the call is going to jquery library file where it tries to makes calls to the server using Ajax and shows time out. But when i created the debug build, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved. I will post the answer for others reference.

1)Primary issue was with meta tag content policy which was trying to block the server which i was trying to connect.
 added connect-src and added my production URL to allow to connect with server

2) second this was with the SSL certificate. Self signed certificate was installed in the server. They removed the self signed certificate and installed a valid trusted SSL certificate.